# how to check HttpWebResponse giving status code 200 or not?

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

im using one api some times some apis gives forbiddend error 403. how to check the status code of webrequest

error
**System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'**

```
var assetTracker = new AssetTracker { deviceid = deviceID };
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
req.Method = "GET";
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "QzdBQ";
req.ContentType = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json";
req.Accept = "application/vnd.onem2m-res+json;";
req.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
req.Headers["X-M2M-RI"] = "99000";
req.Headers["X-M2M-Origin"] = "C7AAC";
// Here I need to check the status code

HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;//getting error
```

Comment: Well if it's throwing a WebException, it definitely isn't a 200. If it doesn't throw an exception, you can use `HttpWebResponse.StatusCode`.

Comment: its throwing exception - System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'

Comment: Using a `try-catch` block, or by using a more friendly API such as HttpClient which doesn't throw if you don't want it to.